# Contour integration for $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{(x+\beta)(x+\gamma)}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have been trying to compute the following integral using contour integration and the residue theorem for quite some time now and can't get it to work out:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{(x+\beta)(x+\gamma)}dx$$
for $0<\alpha<1$ and $\gamma,\beta>0$. I assume that we consider the function $f(z) = \frac{z^{\alpha -1}}{(z+\beta)(z+\gamma)}$, where $z^{\alpha -1}= e^{(\alpha-1)\log z}$.  What should we choose our contour to be? I have tried things like a keyhole contour but they don't seem to work.

Comment: [Keyhole contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts) is actually the very thing you need.

Comment: Well, I suppose that's good to hear. However, I am having a difficult time showing that the contour around the larger circle and smaller circle go to zero in the limit.

Comment: [Estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)?

Comment: All right, that helped with the contour around the larger circle. However, the contour around the smaller circle seems a bit trickier.

Comment: let $\delta = 1 - \alpha$ so $0 < \delta < 1$. So $f(z) = \frac 1{z^\delta(z+ \beta)(z + \gamma)}$. The $z+\beta$ and $z+\gamma$ factors are practically constant near $0$, so the integral over the small circle is effectively $\frac1{\beta\gamma}\int \frac {dz}{z^\delta}$. You can calculate that integral directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{res}}$(to remove this from "unanswered")

Let $\log:\Bbb C^\star\to\Bbb C$ be the logarithm defined by $0\le\arg<2\pi$. Let $0<\alpha<\color{red}{2}$ and $\beta,\gamma>0$. On $\Bbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$, we have a meromorphic function $f:z\mapsto(z+\beta)^{-1}(z+\gamma)^{-1}\exp((\alpha-1)\log z)$. From now on, read $z^{\alpha-1}$ as $\exp((\alpha-1)\log z)$.

*The case $\alpha=1$ is to be momentarily discarded, then once we have a result we take limits as $\alpha\to1$. The final results must be understood as limits for $\alpha=1$*.

The standard keyhole contour works. Observe that $|zf(z)|$ is asymptotically equivalent to $|z|^{\alpha-2}$ as $|z|\to\infty$, which vanishes uniformly. Therefore the large arc vanishes (by the estimation lemma and some basic analysis, no explicit bounds required). Similarly, $|zf(z)|$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\beta^{-1}\gamma^{-1}\cdot|z|^\alpha$ as $|z|\to0$, which vanishes uniformly. Therefore the small arc vanishes.

Fix $x>0$. As $z\to x$ in the *upper* half plane: $$f(z)\to\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{(x+\beta)(x+\gamma)}$$As $z\to x$ in the *lower* half plane: $$f(z)\to e^{2\pi i\alpha}\cdot\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{(x+\beta)(x+\gamma)}$$

Assume $\beta\neq\gamma$.

We conclude that: $$(1-e^{2\pi i\alpha})\cdot J=2\pi i\cdot(\res(f;-\beta)+\res(f;-\gamma))$$
Where $J$ is your integral.

Then all poles are simple and we can find the residues by inspection: $$J=-\pi\cdot e^{-\pi i\alpha}\cdot\frac{2i}{e^{\pi i\alpha}-e^{-\pi i\alpha}}\cdot\left(\frac{\beta^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{\pi i\alpha-\pi i}}{\gamma-\beta}+\frac{\gamma^{\alpha-1}\cdot e^{\pi i\alpha-\pi i}}{\beta-\gamma}\right)$$Which simplifies to: $$J=\pi\csc\pi\alpha\cdot\frac{\gamma^{\alpha-1}-\beta^{\alpha-1}}{\beta-\gamma}$$

Now assume $\beta=\gamma$. Then: $$(1-e^{2\pi i\alpha})\cdot J=2\pi i\cdot\res(f;-\beta)$$The residue will be the first order term in the Taylor expansion of $z\mapsto z^{\alpha-1}$ at $-\beta$, which is $e^{\pi i\alpha}(\alpha-1)\cdot\beta^{\alpha-2}$. We find: $$J=\pi\csc\pi\alpha\cdot(1-\alpha)\beta^{\alpha-2}$$